# Fitting the moving average model

Tags: r, time-series, arima

let v to be forecasted value for periods 1 through T and $v_{t}$ be its forecasted value at time $t$. We express $v_{t}$  as the sum of two terms, its mean at time $t$,  and its deviation from the mean at time $t$, $\epsilon_{t}$. In other words, $$ v_{t}= \overline{v_{t}} + \epsilon_{t} $$ 
The $\overline{v_{t}}$ are chosen based on the arguments. The $\epsilon_{t}$  term is assumed to be a normally distributed random variable with mean zero and standard deviation $\sigma (ε_{t})=0.234$.

The moving average formation of order q is choosen, MA(q) where q is the number of lagged terms in the moving average. We use the following moving average specification:
$$\epsilon_{t} = \sum^{q}_{i=0}{\alpha_{i} \mu_{t-i}} $$

where $\mu_{t-i}$ are independently distributed standard normal random variables. To ensure that the standard deviation of $εt$ is equal to its pre-specified value, we set the
$$\alpha_{i}= \frac{\sigma(\epsilon_{t})}{\sqrt{q+1}}$$
Note that $\epsilon t$ depends on $q+1$ random terms.

the R-code that i have used for above model

```
q=31
iter=10000
for(i in 1:31){alpha_i[i] <- 0.234/(sqrt(31+1))}
err_pk <- array(0,c(iter,11))
for(i in 1:iter){err_pk[i,] <- arima.sim(list(order=c(0,0,31), ma=alpha_i), n=11, innov=rnorm(iter,0,1))}
ffe <- array(0,11)
for(i in 1:11){ffe[i] <- median(err_pk[,i])}`
plot.ts(ffe)
```

I am wondering that, $\alpha$ is changing through time?

and also i never get the same output as in the figure 2 [The end of world Population growth Nature, v412, 543](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v412/n6846/extref/412543a0_S1.htm)

the parameter for figure in the paper are:

Note: MA(30), (31 terms), $\sigma(\epsilon_{t})=0.234$, 31 initial values of $\mu=0$, 10,000 simulation

Am I missing any thing?